# How to randomize order of controls in a flow layout panel in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to make a quiz and need to know how to shuffle or randomize the order of controls in a flow layout panel.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is the type of the controls inside the panel?

Comment: Think data, not controls.  Why shuffle controls around when you can just "randomize" the data (answers, presumably).  Please read [ask] and take teh [tour].